# How to update a table with recent and second recent record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create an aggregate table using the combination of two others.

Feed Table A:

```
PrimaryKey, Score, DateField
1, 50, 1/1/2016
2, 12, 1/1/2016
1, 75, 1/12/2016
1, 80, 1/15/2016
2, 35, 1/16/2016
```

Expected Result (Table B):

```
PrimaryKey, Score, LastScore, OtherFields...
1, 80, 75, data...
2, 35, 12, data...
```

In record 1, 80 is the most recent record, 75 is the 2nd most recent record.  For all records in Table B, this is the rule.

The condition is that there's over 25Million Records in Table A, and 250Million Records in Table B.  Table B gets routinely updated by Table A.

I'm using statements like this:

```
;with cte as
(
    select 
        PrimaryKey, 
        row_number() over(partition by PrimaryKey order by DateField desc) RowNumber
    from 
        TableA
)
```

But my problem is that I'm having issues figuring out how to set first column with one match, and second column with another.

IS there an easier/faster way to do this? I'm hoping to run this in a few hours, not a few days.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses conditional aggregation:

```
with a as (
      select a.PrimaryKey,
             max(case when seqnum = 1 then score end) as score,
             max(case when seqnum = 2 then score end) as score_previous
      from (select a.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by PrimaryKey order by DateField desc) as seqnum
            from TableA a
           ) a
      where seqnum <= 2  -- This should help performance of the `group by`
      group by a.PrimaryKey
     )
select b.*, a.score, a.score_previous
from b join
     a
     on b.primarykey = a.primarykey;
```

Comment: You should add a `WHERE a.seqnum <= 2` in the CTE, I don't assume that SQL Server is smart enough to do that automatically.

Comment: @arcee123 . . . I don't understand your comment.  The question seems to be about a `select` statement.

Comment: no.  I was using a select statement to work the update.  my issue was performance and the ability to tie newest and 2nd newest.  I need to know now how to tie what you recommended into the update.

Comment: I replaced the `select b*....` with an `update b` and it worked.  Really fast too.  Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

If SQL Server version >= 2012 then:

```sql
declare @t table(PrimaryKey int, Score int, DateField date);

insert into @t values 
    (1, 50, '2016-01-01'),
    (2, 12, '2016-01-01'),
    (1, 75, '2016-01-12'),
    (1, 80, '2016-01-15'),
    (2, 35, '2016-01-16');

select top 1 with ties
    PrimaryKey,
    Score,
    LastScore = LAG (Score, 1, null) over (partition by PrimaryKey order by DateField),
    DateField
from
    @t
order by
    row_number() over(partition by PrimaryKey order by DateField desc);
```

**Edit**: if I understood you right, an update would look like this:

```sql
declare @t table(PrimaryKey int, Score int, LastScore int, DateField date);

insert into @t
    (PrimaryKey, Score, DateField)
values 
    (1, 50, '2016-01-01'),
    (2, 12, '2016-01-01'),
    (1, 75, '2016-01-12'),
    (1, 80, '2016-01-15'),
    (2, 35, '2016-01-16');


with cte as 
(
    select
        PrimaryKey,
        Score,
        LastScore = LAG (Score, 1, null) 
                        over (partition by PrimaryKey order by DateField),
        DateField
    from
        @t
)
update t set
    LastScore = cte.LastScore
from 
    @t t
    inner join cte on cte.PrimaryKey = t.PrimaryKey 
                  and cte.DateField = t.DateField               
               -- and cte.Score = t.Score 
where
    t.LastScore is null and cte.LastScore is not null;
```

To make the query faster, make sure you have indexes on both tables:

```sql
create nonclustered index IX_PrimaryKey_DateField on TableA 
(
    PrimaryKey asc,
    DateField asc
) 
include (Score);

GO

create nonclustered index  IX_PrimaryKey_DateField on TableB 
(
    PrimaryKey asc,
    DateField asc
) 
include (Score, LastScore)
where LastScore is null;
```

Comment: HI @Vadim.  Thank you so much.  can you tie this into an update?

Comment: I used the other query as it was faster for me, but your indexe suggestions were used.  Thanks much.